# FTDI FT231XS fails to enumerate

Tags: usb, usb-device, ftdi

I am using an FTDI [FT231XS](https://ftdichip.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/10/DS_FT231X.pdf) chip to communicate between a PC and a TI DSP.  I have verified the correct drivers are installed, but the FT231 doesn't enumerate when I connect it to the PC.
I've compared the schematic to a evaluation board from Sparkfun and don't see anything that looks like it would cause an issue. Any help is appreciated.

[image]

Comment: what OS are you using? ... is anything detected when plugged in?

Comment: It's likely just an image artifact, but GND connection near the USB connector looks funny.   If I saw this in Altium, I would suspect that the connection was actually a graphical line that would result in no electrical connection.  Be sure the GND pin is actually physically connected to GND on your PCB.

Comment: OS is Win 10, nothing shows up at all in device manager, known or unknown.

I forgot to mention I verified the reset line is high

Not sure why the ground line is messed up in the picture.  It's ok in the layout and I just verified it physically.

Comment: Is GPIOF9 being properly configured in code prior to connection?

Comment: Should have put it in the post, but yes, GPIOF9 is outputting high, and verified on pin 14 that it's at 3.3V

Comment: Actually measure the supply voltage, the values of the 47R resistors (power off and unplugged) and the voltage at /RESET. Trace the USB connections. Check those 47pF caps are not 47nF.

Comment: Many of the GND symbols look different from each other, implying that they are different nets (and not connected to each other).  Is that really the case?

Comment: I don't know why they look different.. Verified with a meter they are all connected to each other

Comment: R542 is measuring 27 Ohm... but R543 is measuring open.... will look into it

Comment: What CAD package is this (and version)?  The inconsistent junction dots near J9 makes me really nervous.  The potential nazi-junction near R543 (where the connection crosses), if actually connected, could ruin your day.

Comment: I don't know.... I don't do the design, I'll have to ask the guy that did it.  I double checked the measurements on the two resistors and I must have missed the firsrt time, they are both reading 27 ohms

Comment: The configuration matches neither bus powered or self powered configuration. What kind of device you are intending to build here?

Comment: Intention was to be bus powered.  I just need simple comms between the PC and micro.  I think they based it off of the sparkfun board (http://cdn.sparkfun.com/datasheets/BreakoutBoards/ft231x-breakout-v11.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

The configuration matches neither bus powered or self powered configuration in the datasheet.

It does not match the Sparkfun board either.

The VCC is connected like bus powered but VCCIO is connected like self powered.

The chip can't work properly when incorrectly connected.

And you need some extra isolation between MCU and this USB chip as if you want it to be bus powered you can't have power flowing into it from MCU via the IO pin protection diodes.

Comment: Thank you for the thoughts... I'll review and make changes